# Update Specific part of my .vb file

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i have a function list of 75000 for my project . I want to load each class file dynamically and need to add one line on top of the function and to lines in the ending . Which is the best way to update a specific part of the file . I don't want to make a small mistake here since its my source code and globally using .

Comment: If you're concerned about ruining your source code with a "small mistake", that suggests that you are not using any form of source control!  Be sure you have backups of your code somewhere, then!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to do that at all. You have 75,000 global functions? You are breaking the rules of object-oriented programming in a severe way.

Also, it's not possible without some terrible reflection and dynamic compilation hacks which would slow things to a crawl.

Comment: dude , can you tell me how it breaking the rule of OOP , if it is which rule ?

Comment: I am asking , i have few source files , just wana edit all functions and need to include new line code in that . i can handle it as text file , but its very difficult ..

Comment: i wana know , if there is any other way .

Comment: @VibinKesavan: It's breaking just about every rule of OOP, most likely. It's possible there's a good reason for those 75,000 global functions, but I seriously doubt it. May we have a code example of a couple of those functions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a text file editor that can do a search and replace in the files. For example, replace all occurrences of

```
End Function
```

with

```
    NewLineText1
    NewLineText2
End Function
```

And the same with sub.

Adding the line at the top of the function will be a little more challenging, but I am sure with some good regex or decent support from the search and replace tool, this should be pretty easy to figure out.

We use Search and Replace from [funduc](http://www.funduc.com/), but they have other tools as well and I'm sure there are a ton out there that will do the job.

You could also do the same thing with a macro within visual studio, which, now that I think about it, may be even easier.

For example (pseudo-code):

```
Search for " sub "
If the previous word is not "End"
  Jump to the end of the line
  Add a new line
  Go to the beginning of the new line
  Add your new text
Else
  Jump to the beginning of the current line
  Add a new line (to force the End Sub down)
  Go up a line (if you are still on the end sub line)
  Add your new lines.
```